# Azure Search, is it possible to use Suggestions and Profile Scoring in the same query

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search

I have a search service which return a set of results for each character typed in the search box.

For this I use the Suggestion service, to receive results base on sub string. 
Now I would like to order the results base on numerical values attached to each one of them.

Is it possible to use Profile Scoring ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suggestions in Azure Search ranks the response based on contextual information and matching mechanism used, and unfortunately it doesn't allow customizing the ranking model. If you feel that this would be an important feature, feel free to suggest it on our [user voice](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263029-azure-search).

That said, I can think of a couple workarounds.

workaround 1. You can model a type-ahead like scenario with [custom analysis](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/Custom-analyzers-in-Azure-Search?redirectedfrom=MSDN) via EdgeNGramTokenFilter in Search. Then, you will be able to use a scoring profile.

workaround 2. Rerank the response from Suggestions. This will involve issuing multiple look up queries with document IDs from Suggestions to retrieve the field to rank on and will be slow.

Hope this helps.

Nate

Comment: if you can explain more about the first workaround, the link you gave is the feedback page.
I'm trying to use regular search, not suggestions, and adding * to search as prefix, this works fine although also disable the scoring profile

Comment: Apologies, I updated the link. Could you contact me at nateko _AT_ microsoft.com?